# Font-size menu change iframe-container height

Tags: iframe, ckeditor

I have iframe where I open CKeditor. When the user opens a font size menu, all the content in the body goes to the top (outside iframe). The height of the body doesn't change.
How to prevent iframe content from moving outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use iframe without scrollbar, just set  `overflow: hidden` to iframe  style.

Comment: Thank you. It has helped me